# iOS TestFlight - External Testers Not Notified of New Build

Tags: ios, testflight

I have made an app available to external TestFlight users. They have received the email and installed the app as expected. They have version 1.0, Build 1.

However, I have now uploaded a new build (Version 1.0, Build 2).

This has received approval. In the External Testing page, I have added and selected the new version. This new build now says 'Testing'.

However, the users of the previous build have not received any notification and in the TestFlight app it still says Build 1.

Does anyone know how I can make the current users get the new build? I assumed this would be automatic and I can't find any info on this situation.

Comment: See the same issue

Comment: @Sparked how you uploaded build?

Comment: Hi, I used the 'Upload to App Store ...' option on the archives window in Xcode.

Comment: With fastlane. But this must not have any effect on the fact that testers don't get notifications.

Comment: I also have this issue. Got the processing email but no notification of new TestFlight and testers are unable to test. Old version is reporting that it has been removed from testing on the Apple Watch.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue but for me, some users are getting notified and some are not. I have checked my spam folder with no help there. Also I have a random mix of "installed <previous version>", "installed <current version>", and "notified." I have myself on the list under a different email account and it says "notified" but I was never notified. Additionally, my buddy installed it and gave me feedback but his status still says "notified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be working today; it seems to be a bug in Apple's side where the selection of the new version in TestFlight isn't correctly propagating out to the other systems. You'll find people on twitter and [Apple's developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46028) complaining of the same issue. It affects internal testers too.

I think we just have to wait for Apple to fix it; presumably that will happen in the next 24 hours...

Comment: As JospehH says it was a problem Apple's side. I've just had about fifty emails come through from TestFlight and it is now working.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? What is the normal behavior?  This question is the only documented behavior I can find online on this subject.

Comment: @jungledev It worked fine for me the last time I tried it. I think we'd have seen more complaints if it was still broken.

Comment: Maybe it's an intermittent issue? I am having this problem half a year later.

Answer (score 2):

to send new notification for external testing through testflight you can use the following steps

- first click on "Not available for Testing" and Save
- then click on the Build that you want to test again. Save and Press Start Testing.
  this will send a fresh invitation mail to all the testers you added for testing in testflight.

Comment: Hi @Abhinandan_Pratap, I had already tried that one, I'm afraid, and just tried again. I got the message saying that the current testers would be emailed but that hasn't happened. I'm guessing this is a bug.

Comment: i also faced the same problem when i invite external testers first time for testing in testflight. i follow these steps and it works for me.

Comment: It appears to be something to do with the email addresses. If I add a different email address the email is sent, but not to existing testers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from Apple. What finally solved for me was keeping the "Automatically notify users" checkbox unchecked during the process to invite the users and then AFTER the invitation is complete you go into the build and click "notify users" on the top right corner.

Answer (score -1):

go to TestFlight then in internal Testing

click on edit button and remove the user email id and save .

after saving again add that user id email id which you want invite

Comment: but Sparked is asking for external testing

Comment: I've now tried this option, as well (except on external testers), although it's really a last resort. Imagine doing this with 2000 testers. Still no email sent to the users, I'm afraid.